# Ubuntu SDK Error --

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, chromebook, sdk

When I go to make a Kit after the SDK wizard loads, I am presented with this error, and if I proceed I see it again while attempting to created a device emulator.

> Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening
>   current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such
>   device or address ---Click exited with errors, please check the
>   output---

Let me know if there's any printout that would provide useful information to solve this. I am learning as I go so tips about debugging generally are useful.

Novices need a process, please keep this in mind if you are into documentation for the Ubuntu Touch. Thanks.

- MEAM -

PS I am attempting to build an Ubuntu dev environment in an Ubuntu Wily chroot on an Acer Chromebook 11, implemented with help from the Crouton script.